# Python redis-py multiprocessing: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing, redis-py

I'm trying to parallelize a function in python which interacts with redis using redis-py package. To achieve this task I'm using multiprocessing pool, however I'm getting the `TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object` error while doing it. The reason I'm getting this error is because, we cannot pickle `StrictRedis()` class instance. Kindly find my sample code for more information.

**Note:** Evidently, I searched on google and also explored the stackoverflow but no luck.

Sample Code:

```py
from redis import StrictRedis
from multiprocessing import Pool


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.r = StrictRedis("localhost", 6380)

    def func(self, x, y):
        z = self.r.get("z")
        print(x + y + z)

    def run(self):
        args = [("a", "b"), ("c", "d")]

        with Pool(10) as p:
            p.starmap(self.func, args)


m = Main()
m.run()
```

**Solution 1:**
What I did is to initialize the `StrictRedis()` class in func() method like this in below snippet. But that'll create new instances of `StrictRedis()` for each processes and I don't find this adequate.

```py
def func(self, x, y):
    r = StrictRedis("localhost", 6380)
    z = r.get("z")
    print(x + y + z)
```

Comment: You answered your own question: each process needs to have its own `StrictRedis` instance. That object cannot safely be shared between processes.

Comment: Is there a reason it has to be multiprocessed? For something that's redis-driven you might be better off going with a multithreaded approach or redis pipeline strategy.

Comment: The reason I'm going with multiprocessing is because I want to utilise all the CPUs and this doesn't go well with multithreaded approach.